# How to use functions from an other files.coffee

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, include, require

I have 3 files, one as a main.coffee and 2 other files : file1.coffee and file2.coffee with different functions. I want to use the function in my main file (as include in C)

main.coffee

`exemple1 = function1fromfiles1("hello")
exemple2 = function1fromfiles2("hello")`

file1.coffee

`function1fromfiles1=(word)->
    console.log "file1"+word
    return true`

file2.coffee

`function1fromfiles2=(word)->
    console.log "file2"+word
    return true`

I tried with require but I have error message:

`ReferenceError: function1fromfiles1 is not defined
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/node/file1.coffee:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/node/file1.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)`

if someone can help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

file1.coffee:

```
module.exports = (word)->
  console.log "file1"+word
  return true
```

file2.coffee:

```
module.exports = (word)->
  console.log "file2"+word
  return true
```

main.coffee:

```
function1fromfiles1 = require('./file1.coffee')
function1fromfiles2 = require('./file2.coffee')
exemple1 = function1fromfiles1("hello")
exemple2 = function1fromfiles2("hello")
```